# Get the object with the max attribute value in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes, max

`nodes_ancestors` is a list of objects with a `level` attribute.

I would like to get the object from the list with the highest level value, but I just get the highest value with:

```
ancestor = max(node.level for node in nodes_ancestors)
```

What is right way to do it?

Comment: As always, don't forget to think about what you want to happen if there could be multiple objects with the same value of `level`.

Comment: @DSM : yes thats right, but in this case any object with highest value is required

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and the [`key` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#key-function) of `max`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
ancestor = max(nodes_ancestors, key=attrgetter('level'))
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> class Obj:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.attr = val
...
>>> lst = [Obj(x) for x in range(10)]
>>> obj = max(lst, key=attrgetter('attr'))
>>> obj
<__main__.Obj object at 0x021C2290>
>>> obj.attr
9
>>>
```

Comment: How could I do that if I wanted to get the object with the highest return value for its function `foo(self)`? I don't think I could use `attrgetter`, right?  Probably just loop and select manually?

Comment: use a namedtuple to set values to the return of function foo