# How to get a list of objects by maximum attribute value from N multi-list of objects?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools, getattribute

I have a multi-list of objects as follows (simplified version)

```
listA = [[obj1(val=1),obj2(val=1)],[obj2(val=4),obj3(val=2)]]
listB = [[obj4(val=1),obj5(val=1)],[obj6(val=5),obj7(val=3)]]
listC = [[obj8(val=1),obj9(val=1)],[obj10(val=6),obj11(val=4)]]
```

---

I want to get a list of objects from the above multi-list which has the maximum value of a certain attribute by comparing the sub-lists of each multi-list. If the value of the attribute is the same for all the compared objects, it should get any one object.

output:

```
maxList = [obj1(value=1),obj10(val=6)]
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209255/get-the-object-with-the-max-attribute-value-in-a-list-of-objects) to get object with maximum value of attribute from a list, but this case is for multi-list. I know this can be acheived with nested for loops, but there a must be a better way to do this with itertools and getattr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, let's demonstrate on regular integers.  Adapt this approach to your object.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


a = [[1, 1], [3, 2]]
b = [[1, 1], [5, 3]]
c = [[1, 1], [6, 3]]
```

**Code**

```
list(map(max, [list(it.chain(*col)) for col in zip(a, b, c)]))
# [1, 6]
```

Equivalently

```
[max([x for x in it.chain(*col)]) for col in zip(a, b, c)]
# [1, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. You can do for 'N' multi-list by merging all the multi-list into one big list - mylists=[a,b,c,...] . And then replace zip(a,b,c) with zip(*mylists).